# Abstract method for return class's instance

Tags: java

I have a class and I would like to create one abstract method for return instance of class byself.
For example...

```
public abstract class A {
.........
public abstract Object getInstance();
}
```

```
public class B extends A {
 @Override
 public Object getInstance() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

```
public class C extends A {
 @Override
 public Object getInstance() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Above codes , method `getInstance()` can't force to return instances of child classes `B` and `C`. This is my main point to get it. How could I create an **abstract method** to force for return instance of child classes ?

Comment: do you want to return `B` or `A` from the first example or `C` or `A` in the second? it isn't clear at all.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I just want to have every child classes of `A` have one method to return instance of theirself. For example ...class `C` has a method for return object `Class C` and B , D , E also.

Comment: **Why** you want to do this I have no idea, this makes no logical sense, you have to have a reference to the object to begin with to call `.getInstance();` which only returns you the same reference you already have. *What you are asking for has no functional purpose.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What you are looking for are generic methods:

```
public class Q22213940
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final B b = new B();
        final C c = new C();

        System.out.println("b = b.getInstance() " + b == b.getInstance());
        System.out.println("c = c.getInstance() " + c == c.getInstance());
    }

    public static class C extends A
    {
        @Override
        public C getInstance()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A
    {
        @Override
        public B getInstance()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    public abstract static class A
    {
        public abstract <T> T getInstance();
    }
}
```

#### Why? This serves no functional purpose.

*Why you want to do this I have no idea, this makes no logical sense, you have to have a reference to the object to begin with to call `.getInstance();` which only returns you the same reference you already have.*

Comment: yes, I am sure .. it is my answer. Thanks for great teaching. It is the best way for my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return the Abstract class A itself?

```
public abstract class A {
  .........
  public abstract A getInstance();
}
```

Comment: I have one parent class and there has many child class. But I need to force create one method to return it's instance.

Answer (score 0):

`public abstract B getInstance();`

Implementing this method in a class will allow any code that IS-A B to return. This a co-variant return, where a return type can be the class type or a sub-class of the class type. So this would include an instance of class C because C IS-A B through inheritance since C extends from B.

So a class could override this method like so:

```
    public class C extends A { 

        public B getInstance(){ 
           return new C(); // return a C object 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because A is abstract you can't create an instance of it.  The code below will force the subclasses to implement there own implementation.

```
public abstract class A {
  ............
  public abstract A getInstance();

}
```